# Create a session in OpenCmis without login credentials

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, opencms

My Alfresco Share application is externally authenticated using LDAP. I have some operations to be performed in Alfresco share which i am doing through OpenCmis from java application . Now the problem is , as it is external authentication , i wont have username and password to login into Alfresco , so how do i create a session in OpenCmis without username and password ? any other alternative way i can achieve it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just authenticate with the LDAP details to Alfresco as well?

Comment: i need to create session with opencmis to perform some operations, and i need some mechanism where i can create session without using username and password

Comment: How will Alfresco know who you are though? How will it know what user permissions to apply?

Comment: Wont logging in with ticket generated from Alfresco work for authenticate the user . https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-api/connecting-cmis-using-authentication-ticket-06092011-0836

Comment: that is true that you can use the ticket but for generating ticket also you need to pass user credentials to webscript which will return you ticket and you can use that ticket for your subsequent calls.

Comment: there is an external SSO which occurs , so whenever i hit the url , the SSO should handle the request , authenticate on behalf of the user and i can retrieve the ticket ? is this possible ?

Comment: @user3048258 Finally you found any solution for this?